# Excel VBA: find the union of two tables

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to [vba](/questions/tagged/vba) and I've got two updating columns of text & I want to find the union of the two columns.

*For Example*

```
+---------+---------+
| ColumnA | ColumnB |
+---------+---------+
|   ABC   |    F    |
|   DE    |    F    |
|   F     |   AB    |
|   DBCA  |   CDE   |
|   E     |         |
+---------+---------+
```

I want to write the result in a new column `columnC` (**order doesn't matter**)

```
+---------+
| ColumnC |
+---------+
|   ABC   |
|   F     |
|   DE    |
|   DBCA  |
|   E     |
|   AB    |
|   CDE   |
+---------+
```

How to work out this? Thanks.

Comment: Here is a possible solution to your problem which doesn't require VBA: https://blog.jamesbayley.com/2013/03/14/create-the-union-of-two-tables-in-excel/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**edited**: added removal of duplicated values

try this

```
Sub main()
    With Worksheets("Columns") '<--| change "Columns" to your actual worksheet name
        With .Range("A1", .Range("A1").End(xlDown))
            .Parent.Range("C1").Resize(.Rows.Count).Value = .Value
        End With
        With .Range("B1", .Range("B1").End(xlDown))
            .Parent.Range("C1").End(xlDown).Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count).Value = .Value
        End With
        .Range("C1", .Range("C1").End(xlDown)).RemoveDuplicates Array(1)
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @Ralph: you're right about unique values, I didn't notice it at my first (and too fast) reading of OP's question. I added a `RemoveDuplicates()` method on the final column C "used" range

Comment: Slick and short! Like it. *(+1)*

Comment: Yes, I think my case is Union.

Comment: Thanks @Ralph and SophieFu

Comment: Thanks a lot. @user3598756